# Append options to dynamic dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select boxes that are created dynamically as shown below. 
I also have an ajax call that populates options for the dynamic select boxes. What I want is for the call options to append to the correct  with a generated ID such as `id='quantity 1' / id='quantity 2'`. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

```
 var Html = '';
 for var( i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var qty = lines[i].qty_printed;

      Html += '<select id='quantity"' + qty + "'>
 }
 return Html;
```

My call for the options

```
    $.ajax({
       url: ...,
       success: function(response){

            var results = response.results;
            $('#quantity??').append('<option></option>');

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var option = '<option value=one>' + desc + '</option>'

            $('#quantity??').append(option);
        }
     }
   });
```

Comment: the id `#quantity` should be fixed (it's of the `select`). The indexed ids should be set for your `options`. So it's just simple, isn't it? You have the index run by `i`, just compose all to form the HTML string of each `option` (similarly to what you've done).

Comment: Yes, but I am generating multiple <select> tags. So the ID would be more like #quantity1, #quantity2, etc...

Comment: from what you posted, I don't see how you could generate multiple <select> unless you call your ajax request multiple times, is that right?

Comment: btw, what is the first code snippet about? it does not look like related to the second snippet. The first code snippet seems to try to generate multiple selects.

Comment: why dont you use your i variable in javascript function to make your id unique in select tag

Comment: The ID for the select has to be unique. I just added a name to each select and appended that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this.

```
$("select[id*="'+ qty +'"]").append(option);
```